# С# как воспроизвести MPEG-2 TS?

Tags: c#

Пробовал плеер на `DirectX 1.0.2902.0` - умирает от `MPEG-2 TS`
(библиотеки `Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.dll` и `Microsoft.DirectX.dll`)

Пробовал плеер на `Interop.QuartzTypeLib.dll` - умирает от `MPEG-2 TS` ([источник](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2632/DirectShow-MediaPlayer-in-C))

Дошел до варианта с `MediaElement` ([источник](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/How-to-Use-Media-Element-b8ce7e92)), грубо закоментировал `dialog.Filter = "WMV file (.wm)|*.wmv";` - и о чудо `MPEG-2 TS` зашевелился, НО плывет и умирает. Как добиться нормального проигрывания `MPEG-2 TS`?

XAML:

```
<Grid> 
<Grid.RowDefinitions> 
    <RowDefinition Height="320*"/> 
    <RowDefinition Height="50*"/> 
</Grid.RowDefinitions> 
<MediaElement x:Name="MediaPlayer" Grid.RowSpan="1" LoadedBehavior="Manual"/> 
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"> 
    <Button x:Name="btnPlay" Content="Play" Click="btnPlay_Click" Width="50" Height="25" Margin="5"/> 
    <Button x:Name="btnStop" Content="Stop" Click="btnStop_Click" Width="50" Height="25" Margin="5"/> 
    <Button x:Name="btnMoveBack" Content="Back" Click="btnMoveBack_Click" Width="50" Height="25" Margin="5"/> 
    <Button x:Name="btnMoveForward" Content="Forward" Click="btnMoveForward_Click" Width="50" Height="25" Margin="5"/> 
    <Button x:Name="btnOpen" Content="Open" Click="btnOpen_Click" Width="50" Height="25" Margin="5"/> 
</StackPanel>
```

C#

```
public MainWindow() 
{ 
    InitializeComponent(); 
    IsPlaying(false); 
} 

private void IsPlaying(bool flag) 
{ 
    btnPlay.IsEnabled = flag; 
    btnStop.IsEnabled = flag; 
    btnMoveBack.IsEnabled = flag; 
    btnMoveForward.IsEnabled = flag; 
} 

private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    IsPlaying(true); 
    if (btnPlay.Content.ToString() == "Play") 
    { 
        MediaPlayer.Play(); 
        btnPlay.Content = "Pause"; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        MediaPlayer.Pause(); 
        btnPlay.Content = "Play"; 
    } 
} 

private void btnStop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    MediaPlayer.Pause(); 
    btnPlay.Content = "Play"; 
    IsPlaying(false); 
    btnPlay.IsEnabled = true; 
} 

private void btnMoveBack_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    MediaPlayer.Position -= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10); 
} 

private void btnMoveForward_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    MediaPlayer.Position += TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10); 
} 

private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    // Configure open file dialog box 
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dialog = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog(); 
    dialog.FileName = "Videos"; // Default file name 
    dialog.DefaultExt = ".WMV"; // Default file extension 
    //dialog.Filter = "WMV file (.wm)|*.wmv"; // Filter files by extension  

    // Show open file dialog box 
    Nullable<bool> result = dialog.ShowDialog(); 

    // Process open file dialog box results  
    if (result == true) 
    { 
        // Open document  
        MediaPlayer.Source = new Uri(dialog.FileName); 
        btnPlay.IsEnabled = true; 
    } 
}
```

---

В Windows media player `MPEG-2 TS` воспроизводится нормально.

И в плеере на `MediaElement` проблем с `mp4` нет.

Comment: Windows media player как воспроизводит, тоже "плывет"?

Comment: Забыл сразу сказать,что во всех готовых проигрывателях, в том числе в Windows media player воспроизводится нормально. У меня были похожие проблемы на другом компьютере в VLC media player пока я не включил 'аппаратное ускорение'. Но если здесь проблема тоже в аппаратном ускорении, то я не знаю как его включить для моего проигрывателя.

Comment: @Monk , подскажешь как побороть такое поведение, или нет мыслей на этот счет?

Comment: Ну, нагуглить решения мне не удалось. Судя по гуглу, в целом контрол должен вести себя как и WMP, но багов в нём хватает и писать на нём что-то серьезное не советуют.